# What is the MembersInjectors in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

In [the official document](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BuiltInBindings), you can see this sentence.

> When binding to providers or writing extensions, you may want Guice to inject dependencies into an object that you construct yourself. To do this, add a dependency on a MembersInjector (where T is your object's type), and then call membersInjector.injectMembers(myNewObject).

I don't understand the whole picture of how to use `MembersInjector`.
When you want Guice to inject some instances into an object that you want to create, it is good to just make appropriate bindings.   So, when do you use this `MemebersInjector`? 
Even when you want to use providers like `bind().toProvider()`, why don't we need to use `MembersInjector`?

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 3):

The key words here are "that you construct yourself".

For `bind(A.class).to(B.class)`, Guice *creates the `B` instance itself* and injects it according to its `@Inject` constructor, methods, and fields. However, in some cases, you might need to get an instance from somewhere other than Guice. This may be in cases where constructors may not easily accept extra parameters like in [Eclipse SWT](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FDialog.html), or where instances are automatically constructed like in [Java serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), [Google GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), [Apache Crunch](http://crunch.apache.org/user-guide.html#dofns-vs-mapper-and-reducer-classes), or in any other case where instances are created outside of your control.

In those cases, rather than `getInstance(YourClass.class)` or `getProvider(YourClass.class)`, you want Guice to *perform all the injection it can on an instance you already have*. This is where [`MembersInjector`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/MembersInjector.html) comes in: You can inject a `MembersInjector<YourClass>` wherever you need it, or you can use [`Injector.getMembersInjector`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getMembersInjector-java.lang.Class-) to create an arbitrary MembersInjector based on a Class or TypeLiteral.

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer.  However, the methods you mentioned, `getInstance(YourClass.class)` and `getProvider(YourClass.class)`, are Guice's methods?

Comment: Yes, those are methods on Injector, equivalent to injecting `T` or `Provider<T>` within your graph.

Comment: In my system we had a few cases where we would `@Inject private Injector injector` to inject deserialized objects - and Guice 5 doesn't like that at all. So we replaced them with `@Inject private MembersInjector<MyClass> injector` to make Guice happy.